# how to get friend's likes from facebook

Tags: facebook

I am retrieving the complete list of a friend's likes(the list of pages that the user likes) using the code bellow:

```cs
Uri ex_a = new System.Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/" + friend_id + "/likes?    access_token=" + token);
WebClient WC_a = new WebClient();
WC_a.DownloadStringCompleted += new System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(list_likes);
WC_a.DownloadStringAsync(ex_a);

private void list_likes(object ob, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
JsonObject jo = new JsonObject(e.Result);
JsonArray dataArray = (JsonArray)jo["data"];

if (dataArray.ToString().Length > 2)
 {
  foreach (JsonObject account in dataArray)
   {
    list_of_likes.Add(new class_of_likes("http://graph.facebook.com/" + (string)account["id"] + "/picture?type=small", (string)account["name"]));
   }
 }

}
```

However, in October 2013, this approach will only retrieve 25 results/request.
I need to know how to create a loop to get the remaining results because facebook uses pagination like:
"paging": {
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/likes?limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=last_page_id"

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get pagination section, and parse it to get next_page value, then send a query for it. There's no automatic process or get all method , otherwise spams/bots would be the happiest creature in this world.

Comment: I tryed
Uri ex_a = new System.Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/" + friend_id + "/likes?limit=2?access_token=" + token);
and other variations taken as example from graph api explorer and always visual studio throws exceptions.
I don't know how to construct a better request.

Comment: You should read up on the [Batch API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/). It allows you to make multiple requests in one single round-trip to Facebook's servers. Should speed things up considerably.